# Export Truecaller data such as messages, call history

Tags: truecaller

I would like to uninstall [Truecaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller) but obviously be able to retain access to my call history, messages via e.g. the default apps. Is that possible, or is all data received while truecaller was installed & set to be the default app "locked in" by Truecaller? I have scoured the web, this is my last hope...

Comment: Thought about messaging the developer.

Comment: @RohitGupta no word from them yet. Based on moderate research this is by design and infuriating, I'm interested to know if someone somehow had overcome that hurdle and wants to share how.